# NameError: global name 'User' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I follow [miguelgrinberg](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vi-profile-page-and-avatars)  tutorial and want to make a profile page without **Login page** so when I have http:.../user/peg As I said I got error,I think because it couldn't connect with database. I put data in User with python command

```
>>> u = models.User(nickname='peg', email='peg@email.com')
>>> db.session.add(u)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

I have a question that where is the database that store User and Post? And why he didn't define the table?( because in app.db we have a table with three column 1.reponsity_id 2. reponsity_path 3. id) and please tell me how can I solve the error. Thanx

views.py

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'nickname': 'Miguel'}
    posts = [
       {
         'author': {'nickname': 'John'},
         'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland!'
         },
       {
         'author': {'nickname': 'Susan'},
         'body': 'The Avengers movie was so cool!'
       }
    ]
    return render_template("index.html",
                           title='Home',
                           user=user,
                           posts=posts)

 @app.route('/user/<nickname>')
 def user(nickname):
     #here I got error NameError: global name 'User' is not defined
     user = User.query.filter_by( nickname = nickname).first() 
     posts = [
          {'author': user, 'body': 'Test post #1'},
          {'author': user, 'body': 'Test post #2'}
     ]
     return render_template('user.html',
               user=user,
               posts=posts)
```

Models.py

```
from app import db
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.nickname)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
       return '<Post %r>' % (self.body)
```

db_create.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
from app import db
import os.path
db.create_all()

if not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
    SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

> user.html

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>User: {{ user.nickname }}!</h1>
<hr>
{% for post in posts %}
<p>
{{ post.author.nickname }} says: <b>{{ post.body }}</b>
 </p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Format your code, please!

Comment: @ Stefano Sanfilippo , sorry But is there any special comment to format it?

Comment: @Pegasuss: yes, there is. Use the `{}` button on the toolbar (after pasting in your code and making sure it is all selected), or use CTRL-K (or CMD-K on Mac). See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import your models into your `views` module:

```
from models import User
```

Comment: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError

UndefinedError: 'flask.ctx._AppCtxGlobals object' has no attribute 'user' @Martijn Pieters Now I got this error?

Comment: for this line <a href="{{ url_for('user', nickname=g.user.nickname) }}">profile</a></div> @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @Pegasuss: you are using `g.user` there. `g` is the Flask global object, but you have no `user` attribute on there. In your case, you want to use `nickname=user.nickname` perhaps.

Comment: @Pegasuss: do follow the *rest* of the tutorial too; the Flask-Login tutorial includes code that sets `g.user`.

Comment: I don't want to have a login as I said just want to take a user from User to show profile @ Martijn Pieters so can u help?

Comment: @Pegasuss: then don't use `g.user`. Perhaps remove all code from your templates that uses `g.user`?

Comment: Thanx @Martijn Pieters can u tell me about is question: where is the database that store User and Post? And why he didn't define the table?( because in app.db we have a table with three column 1.reponsity_id 2. reponsity_path 3. id

Comment: @Pegasuss: The tutorial uses SQLAlchemy-migrate to handle database migrations. It adds the schema for you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding:

```
class User(flask_login.UserMixin):
     pass
```

Solved the issue for me.